# making Call conference using USB Modem/Android Phone

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, serial-port, putty

As the question's title tell the most about the problem.

Here is some more detail on what I wish to do, but having no background in this field facing many problems to make it possible.

I want to connect a SIM with my Computer using USB Modem, or Android phone which ever solve my question.

Keeping it connected, I read about in some other question that we can make call using **DotRas**, I searched a lot but couldn't find anything for Call conference.

- Is this possible..?
- And if yes, can someone help me to achieve this..?

or at least hint on What should I learn to be able to do this type of work.

Ready to learn in both Windows/Ubuntu, if it is possible in any...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @laalto sorry but i guess it do involve programming, for eg to make communication with the modem even C++/Python etc codes are used. Drivers are made, and many other things.. :/

Comment: If you edited your question so that it was clearly a programming question demonstrating effort of your own, I'd be happy to retract the close vote.